# What is the best way to do button parameter change C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

When the event occurs, the text on all buttons should change. The code is presented below.

```
button1.Text = "";
button2.Text = "";
button3.Text = "";
button4.Text = "";
button5.Text = "";
button6.Text = "";
button7.Text = "";
button8.Text = "";
button9.Text = "";
```

Can I make it simpler, maybe like in arrays using a loop?

Comment: If it was wpf you'd add an event trigger to a style and apply that style to all those buttons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the buttons in a list and then you can manipulate their `text` property in a loop:

```
List<Button> btnLst = new List<Button>()
{
    button1, button2, button3,
    button4, button5, button6,
    button7, button8, button9
};
        
foreach (Button btn in btnLst)
{
    btn.text = "";
}
```

Comment: Should be a foreach of course.

Comment: @PMF please feel free to re-edit my post, as I've edited it and overwritten your contribution by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever container your buttons are in can be asked for its buttons. If they're not in any panel or group box and just sitting in the form they'll be in `this.Controls`:

```
this.Controls
  .OfType<Button>()
  .Where(b => Regex.IsMatch(b.Name,"button[1-9]"))
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(b => b.Text = "");
```

You can probably skip the OfType too, as all controls have a Name and a Text..

If there's something else common about your buttons, such as they have the same tag it could be like

```
this.Controls
  .OfType<Button>()
  .Where(b => b.Tag == "Hello")
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(b => b.Text = "");
```

If all your buttons are in one panel, and nothing else is in there, or if there are other things that aren't buttons, it's easier because you can skip the where

```
this.ThePanel
  .OfType<Button>()
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(b => b.Text = "");
```